# JQuery ul li children

Tags: jquery-selectors

How can I get only "Content II" gets red color not it's children?

css

```
.selected { color:red; }
```

html

```
<ul>
  <li id="item-i">Content I</li>
  <li id="item-ii">Content II
    <ul>
      <li id="item-a">A</li>
      <li id="item-b">B</li>
        <ul>
          <li id="item-1">1</li>         
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

What is wrong here.

```
$('#item-ii').addClass('selected');

$('#item-ii').children().removeClass('selected');
```

I want only "Content II" gets red color not it's children.

Comment: Well, closing the Content II <li> tag would be a start. (Go through and make sure your tags are opened and closed properly.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's inheriting by default.  Set another color explictly.

http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/

Comment: Specifically try: `li { color: black } li.selected{color:red}`

Comment: also: apparently its not illegal/reserved but "selected
" might not be the best class name.  isnt in an attribute for radio boxes or something?